# Do part-time courses count as tuition for tax purposes for a work permit holder?

Tags: income-tax, canada, non-resident, tuition, canada-revenue-agency

My wife is not a Canadian citizen. As her permanent residence application is in process, she has been given a 2-year open work permit, and she used it to work during the 2016 tax year.

Her conditions of stay also allow her to take courses up to 6 months as long as they're not building towards a degree/etc. She took advantage of this to take a part-time French course for 3 months during the 2016 tax year.

Do her tuition costs (approximately $500 CAD) count as tuition for tax purposes? I am filing our joint return and need to know whether it will be a deductible.